# Multiple date options in DateTimePicker ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using active admin.

Is there any way to select `multiple date` in `date_time_picker` of `ActiveAdmin`?

I tried to find it in documentation also, but couldn't find it.

If this is possible, do in need to change the column type in database also?

Currently for single date the data type is `datetime`. Do I need to change it to `array of datetime`?

Comment: More of a data structure design I would say. You can set to have your model have `has_many` relationship to your dates so that your edit page can render nested attributes which you can edit multiple dates.

Comment: Got your point, but it wouldn't help if there is no provision to add multiple date on `date_time_picker` of `active admin`.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no. Formtastic offers `:date_select` and ActiveAdmin adds `:datepicker` and a `:date_range` filter. If you want to select multiple dates you will need to build a [custom Formtastic input](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs) perhaps using an [existing jQuery UI addon](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/)

Comment: Don't have time to integrate these into the current project. Will use it in a future project, Definitely. Thumbs up